# How to show neighboring polygons and polygon in which point exists

Tags: polygon, spatial-database, query, mysql

We have a table which has polygon related data stored.

For finding if a point (long,lat) is within that polygon I am using following query in mysql

```
SET @vasantKunjSectorC =  'polygon((77.161266 28.546614, 77.16029 28.545304))';
CREATE TABLE poly (g polygon);
insert into poly values (GeomFromText(@vasantKunjSectorC))
select * from poly
​
select * from poly where st_within(point(77.143780, 28.539104), g); -- should return 1 record
select * from poly where st_within(point(77.125835, 28.541724), g); -- shouldn't return any record
```

I have following question related to some of the scenario depicted from the diagram below:

[image: Scenario]

You can assume that the data in the poly table is like:

[image: data]

**1-** If the point lies in society 6 then my query should return society 6 and neighbouring societies (with in some km radius defined by user).

**2-** It should not return Area A (which is also a polygon).